# How to change the font of Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, fonts

I was looking for a way to add custom emoticons to Whatsapp, and since [this method](https://www.loudtechie.com/how-to-add-or-edit-whatsapp-custom-emoticons/) simply replaces existing emoticons with new ones I thought about replacing characters from a language I won't use (for example [Tangut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangut_script), the language [this iOS app](https://blog.emojipedia.org/custom-emojis-come-to-ios/) used) with the desired emoticons

I wanted to know how to replace some (or all) of the characters of said language in Whatsapp using a changed font that could be installed on other phones as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to settings in your phone and change the font style.
It will change the font style in whatsapp but not the message font. You can also try installing other keyboards from Google play store with different font styles, emoticon and other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I mainly wanted to know how to create said keyboard. I know it musn't be very hard, but I haven't found any tutorial or resource to do so. Is it just like a regular Windows font, or do I have to use a special program to create it?

Comment: Well it seems like the answer is yes, `.ttf` files are used by Android (or so it seems) so I'll simply mark your aswer as valid, because it did make me realize changing the font of the phone changes the font used by Whatsapp, as obvious as that may sound I figured it used another one